# Dynamically Checking page in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Basically, I'm trying to sign up to a website using Selenium, however, a popup keeps showing up. So I click it, however, when I try to click other parts of the webpage, it wont find them (using element find)

I first tried using classname, Xpath, etc, but nothing worked. When the page first loads up with the popup, it doesnt load in the class for the typing places.

I try to detect it with the following script:

```
def type(class_name, text): 
   try: 
      element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( 
         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)) ) 
      if element: 
         driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element) 
         driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", element, text)
         print(f"Typed '{text}' in the element found by class name!") 
      else: 
         print("Element not found.")
   except Exception:
       #Handle Exception
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you share more of the code, and details around the popup? Unless someone has encountered this exact problem, its hard to find a solution for your issue.

Comment: Yeah, so right now the code im using to try to type is def type(class_name, text):
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, class_name))
        )
        if element:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", element, text)
            print(f"Typed '{text}' in the element found by class name!")
        else:
            print("Element not found.")
(Exception part but I dont have enough characters lef